# Which kernel is compatible in my case

Tags: kernel, 15.10

English is my second language so it's not so good, sorry

My laptop runs cpu i5-6300hq and gtx 960M video card. I recently have installed ubuntu in nomodeset because kernel verson 4.2 didn’t support skylate processor (intel hd 530). Therefore, I had to update to kernel  4.4.3 in order to use intel hd 530 for my second monitor. Everything seemed normal, but there is one problem which is after using my latop for a while, ubuntu stops responding, my mouse and keyboard stop working as well so I have to use the power button to restart the laptop; however, the sound works normally (like music). I have tried reinstalling for many times but it was strange one time that I after I had installed in nomodeset and booted to Ubuntu (kernel version 4.2), Ubuntu automatically detected cpu và intel hd 530, and it happened only once. I don’t understand what is happening with kernel of Ubuntu. I am newbie, please help me to fix it.

Comment: Which Ubuntu desktop version you are using - 14.04 LTS or 15.10?

Comment: Did you install proprietary drivers?

Comment: My ubuntu version is 15.10 Wily Werewolf. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should upgrade to [Linux kernel 4.3](http://www.theinquirer.net/inquirer/news/2433010/linux-kernel-43-brings-intel-skylake-and-open-source-nvidia-support) or 4.4 which has support for Intel skylake and nvidia open source drivers.

After this for nvidia you can try the below steps.

Based on this [link](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/98373/en-us) nvidia-361 is the driver for Nvidia GTX 960

First uninstall the currently installed NVIDIA drivers. Boot the computer, when the GRUB menu appears ...

Highlight the Ubuntu menu entry and press the E key. Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line. Press F10 to boot the Ubuntu operating system.

When the login screen appears press Ctrl+Alt+F1. Enter your user name and the password, then execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

Now install the latest official stable NVIDIA drivers. Boot the computer, when the GRUB menu appears ...

Highlight the Ubuntu menu entry and press the E key. Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line. Press F10 to boot the Ubuntu operating system.

When the login screen appears press Ctrl+Alt+F1. Enter your user name and the password, then execute :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361
sudo reboot
```

Note : Maybe it is explicitly necessary to select the NVIDIA adapter in BIOS. When you want to use drivers 361, adding the PPA is not necessary. In this case the terminal commands you have to perform are these :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361
sudo reboot
```

In case you have installed the nvidia driver from their site then uninstall it as per that instructions.Uninstall that driver by running, as root, `sh ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-361.28.run` and follow the on screen instructions

***Note : The solution I have provide has been tested on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Ubuntu 15.10 for two GPUs.***

Comment: I think kernel already included driver for all devices and I have never installed extra driver before. If it is driver for VGA then I used Bumblebee project but Ubuntu stopped responding while installing and cannot boot for the next time. I will try this solution and tell you the result later. Thank you !

Comment: Yeah, you 're right, I follow your instruction and run software updater and everything work smoothly on 4.2 kernel version. Thanks you very much !

Answer (score 1):

Generally, it's good to have new kernels and microcode when using new processors.

To install kernels from mainline for ubuntu: [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade)

To install intel microcode: Additional drivers > Microcode firmware for intel cpus > apply changes